# Using computer vision instead of algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, search-algorithms, computer-vision, python

I have been thinking of a problem i have here with a calendar scheduler where i basically want to split a year into seconds and have access to the dataset of whole year.

In this year i assign blocks of time that varies in size can be big or can be small, it has to be placed in non assigned places ( which isnt occoupied with blocks already ) - also the option to insert so the map changes all the time.

To do this programatically, if i ex have a 10 day in seconds block i want to fit it, today i would go through the whole year and try to compare 10 days of seconds ( alot of bytes if 1 byte represent a second ) this is a heavy process.

But if i ex illustrate my year visually ( ok it would be a very wide image ) and look at the size of the block i need to fit in, i am visually super fast in spotting places where it might fit or fit.

Would this be possible to do with computervision ? Or will the computing power in computer vision be way over the line compared to what any algorithm can do ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a computer *science* question. If a non-algorithmic solution works, go for it!

Comment: I think you don't know what computer vision means. Also, I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want some scheduling algorithm that behaves similar to a human? Do you expect humans to be better at scheduling and wonder whether imitating/learning that behaviour in computers is feasible?

Comment: Im asking because the scheduling task would be massive datawise to go through sequentially ?

Comment: But agree i dont know much about computer vision it wss an idea i was thinking of to prevent sequential processing bit again dont know if the vision part is much more massive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analogy is mistaken. You assume that, if you glanced at your calendar, you would quickly be able to identify all ten-day blocks of free time. Actually I bet you'd have all kinds of problems with that.

Can you really tell at a glance the difference between a free block of $863\ 999$s (ten days minus a second) and one of $864\,000$s?  Honestly, even if you just divided my calendar into days, I'd have to count the length of blocks between about eight and twelve days to check whether they were really more or less than ten.

Comment: No but with my eyes im able to spot where on a calendar there would be space for ex 10 days - and if i go in close i can spot smaller segments.